# Ajax inline editing mysql results

Tags: java, php, jquery, mysql, inline

I'm getting a list of rows from a MySQL query showing a list of **usernames**, and I need to be able to edit them inline using ajax, but with this script I'm using I can only edit the first one listed in the results, please HELP!

I got these from a mysql result, 3 rows with usernames, and I can only edit inline the first one, but not the other:

```
  <div>
    <span>Username1:</span>
    <a href="#" id="username" data-id2="101">user1</a>
  </div>


  <div>
    <span>Username2:</span>
    <a href="#" id="username" data-id2="102">user2</a>
  </div>


  <div>
    <span>Username3:</span>
    <a href="#" id="username" data-id2="103">user3</a>
  </div>
```

This is my Custom JS script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';     

    //make username editable
    $('#username').editable({

    //uncomment these lines to send data on server
        id: 'id',
        id2: 'id2',
        url: './ajax_editor.php'

    });
});
</script>
```

Please keep in mind that I need to be able to edit (***inline***) each username from the results individually

Here is the JS and CSS source i'm using:

```
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.6/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.6/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

THANKS

Comment: You use `id`. Switch to `class` and you should be fine, if the script is working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `id`

```
<div>
    <span>Username1:</span>
    <a href="#" class="username" data-id2="101">user1</a>
  </div>


  <div>
    <span>Username2:</span>
    <a href="#" class="username" data-id2="102">user2</a>
  </div>


  <div>
    <span>Username3:</span>
    <a href="#" class="username" data-id2="103">user3</a>
  </div>
```

And access via jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';     

    //make username editable
    $('.username').editable({

    //uncomment these lines to send data on server
        id: 'id',
        id2: 'id2',
        url: './ajax_editor.php'

    });
});
</script>
```